# Does the limit $I^{n},n\to\infty$ of ideal of a ring exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Then $I^{n}$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $a_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n},a_{i}\in I,i=1,...,n$. And we have a chain of ideals $I\supset I^{2}\supset\cdot\cdot\cdot\supset I^{n}\supset\cdot\cdot\cdot$. It seems that when $n\to\infty$, $I^{n}$ will be very "small". So I wonder if the limit $I^{n},n\to\infty$ exists? If so, what let the limit make sense? It is known that in the usual case, to define the limit, one needs at least a topology.

Comment: Look like it would be $\bigcap _n I^n$?

Comment: @Arctic Char: You remind me of a proposition about adic rings, which claims that an adic ring with an $\mathfrak{a}$-topology is separated if and only if $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathfrak{a}^{n}=0$. So the limit $I^{n},n\to\infty$ may not tend to 0.

Comment: Indeed, it may not, since sometimes $I^2=I$ with $I\neq 0$.

Comment: @Captain Lama: So in this case, the limit $I^{n},n\to\infty$ is equal to $I$. But it makes no difference.

Comment: Indeed. It's just to show that the behaviour can be very different depending on the specific case.

Answer (score 1):

For any sequence of sets you can define:
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n =\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=j}^{\infty} A_k$$
and
$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} A_n =\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=j}^{\infty} A_k$$
and then define a convergence in a such way that:
a sequence $(A_n)$ is convergent if and only if $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n =\liminf_{n\to \infty} A_n .$$

Comment: I think it would be worth adding that since $I^n$ is decreasing, it is always convergent, precisely to $\bigcap_n I^n$.